# Truststore in TLS connection

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, mtls

According to TLS connection definition, for example, as the client-side, I use keystore to store my private key and certificate, and use truststore to store some kinds of certs. On the server-side, that call it Youtube, it has a root certificate called Youtube.pem which is signed by Google.crt CA.

I know the truststore is to verify the 3rd party certificate during handshake

My question is what should my truststore actually store during handshake?

1. Youtube.pem (the CA signed certificate sent from 3rd part)
2. Google.crt  (the CA certificate)

Comment: These kind of questions should be asked at [security.se], but only after you've tried your best to solve the issue yourself (by learning PKI) and after looking for duplicate questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming related question

Answer (score 1):

> According to TLS connection definition, for example, as the client-side, I use keystore to store my private key and certificate, and use truststore to store some kinds of certs.

Yes, but you only need a keystore if you want to use client side authentication. Note that "keystore" and "truststore" indicate *how the store* is used, they can be of the same type (e.g. PKCS#12) and even the same file.

> On the server-side, that call it Youtube, it has a root certificate called Youtube.pem which is signed by Google.crt CA.

No, YouTube is a service, it has a **leaf** or **end-entity certificate**. The root certificate is that of a third party CA. The end-entity certificate is usually signed by an intermediate CA certificate, and that is in turn signed by a self signed root certificate.

> I know the truststore is to verify the 3rd party certificate during handshake

It is used to validate and verify the **trust path** from leaf certificate to a trust anchor in your truststore. The trust anchor is *usually* one of the root certificates stored in your truststore. The leaf certificate is indicated by the end entity / server, the intermediate certificates are usually sent by the server as well, but they could also be retrieved from a cache.

---

In the case of YouTube, the Google root CA is used, possibly using the GlobalSign root through a linked certificate if the Google root is not present in the trust store.

So your truststore should either contain the Google root certificate or the GlobalSign root for the connection to work in this example.

Comment: this didn't fit in a comment, this is just posted because I was trying to be nice and explain basic PKI concepts to you. I'd strongly suggest you read a book or 2 on the subjects (or use youtube.com and look for a basic explanation :P)